# how to change the pitch of recorded audio getting me following error

Tags: objective-c, avaudiorecorder, pitch-shifting, avaudiofile

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: node != nil'

```
AVAudioFile *file=[[AVAudioFile alloc] initForReading:_recordedvoice error:nil];
AVAudioFormat *format=file.processingFormat;
AVAudioFrameCount capacity= (AVAudioFrameCount)file.length;
AVAudioPCMBuffer *buffer=[[AVAudioPCMBuffer alloc] initWithPCMFormat:format frameCapacity:capacity];
[file readIntoBuffer:buffer error:nil];
[playerNode scheduleBuffer:buffer completionHandler:nil];

engine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc] init];
    playerNode = [[AVAudioPlayerNode alloc] init];

[engine attachNode: playerNode];

AVAudioMixerNode *mixer = engine.mainMixerNode;
AVAudioUnitTimePitch *auTimePitch;
auTimePitch.pitch=1200.0;// In cents. The default value is 1.0. The range of values is -2400 to 2400
auTimePitch.rate = 2.0; //The default value is 1.0. The range of supported values is 1/32 to 32.0.

//get the error in the following line

[engine attachNode: auTimePitch];
[engine connect:playerNode to:auTimePitch format:[mixer outputFormatForBus:0]];
[engine connect:playerNode to:mixer format:[mixer outputFormatForBus:0]];

[playerNode play];
```

Comment: could be something with the completion handler. Check out this stack overflow answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/29630124/5716449

Comment: i m completely new in objective c  i want to change the recorded voice into different voices such girl child etc can you help me....

Comment: check this questions out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100495/real-time-pitch-shifting-on-the-iphone    That should help you on your quest.

Comment: i m not getting properly their can you help me.....

Comment: a lot of them suggested this - http://www.zynaptiq.com/ztx/license-or-evaluate-ztx/

Comment: its not working for me......

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the engine first before calling play:

```
[self.engine startAndReturnError:nil];
[playerNode play];
```

Comment: how to save this pitch changed audio?